# Абстрагированный  связанный список в С

Tags: c

Задача в следующем, у меня есть много структур, которые часто хранятся в списках. Хотелось бы найти решение, которое позволяет создавать списки структур разных типов одинаково. Т.е.  возможно ли в С сделать нечто на подобие шаблонного класса? Сейчас я использую для этого макросы.

Comment: Я к сожалению не работал с этим но есть предположение использовать pointer'ы с каким нибудь полем type для определения типа.
И еще не понятно зачем это нужно, если это из-за вызова множества функций то не лучше ли сделать переопределение функций с разными входными параметрами и некой общей функции с расчетом и передачей в нее ссылки на функцию сравнения или что там требуется.

Answer (score 2):

Только через макросы к сожалению. Первая реализация С++ в свое время тоже была написана на С и помощью макросов, так что такой вариант не самый плохой.

Comment: Из за макросов, по моему мнению, сильно падает читаемость кода.

Comment: Из за макросов падает не только читаемость. Но если нужно сделать то что другим способом не сделать, то нужно написать макрос так чтобы читаемость была приемлемой.

Answer (score 0):

```
struct gen_list {
  struct gen_list *next, *prev;
  int             value_type;
  void            *value;
};

struct gen_list *list_elem;
```

В *value* заносим указатель на структуру в списке,
в *value_type* тип структуры.
*next/prev* - указатели на следующий/предыдущий в списке (все как обычно)
Для доступа к структурам :

```
switch (list_elem->value_type) {
  case 1:
    p_stru1 = (t_stru1 *)(list_elem->value);
  ...
}
```

Конечно типы структур предопределены на этапе компиляции.

Comment: Данное решение не подходит. Так как это тоже самое, что и макросы.

Comment: Вопрос же был не в том чтобы создать список для хранения разных типов структур (аналог наследования). А создать список в котором хранятся структуры одного типа, но иметь возможность на его основе создать другой список с другими структурами (аналог абстрагирования времени компиляции - шаблонов).